# bash: get value from dynamic variable

Tags: bash

assume I have the following function.

```
tempStr="${1^^}_DOCKER_DEPLOY_KEY"
export $tempStr=gggg
value="${!tempStr}"
echo "The value is ${value}"
```

How can I inline this "converting" logic to echo command instate of ${value}? I just want fewer lines of code.

thx

Comment: `eval 'echo "$'"${1^^}"'_DOCKER_DEPLOY_KEY"'`. See [BashFAQ#048](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) before using it though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by "inline", is this what you need :

```
export "${1^^}_DOCKER_DEPLOY_KEY=gggg"
echo "The value is $(env|awk -F= '$1 ~ /_DOCKER_DEPLOY_KEY/{print $2}')"
```